# Problema al crear mi ejecutable .JAR en java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Trato de crear un archivo ejecutable .JAR para mi aplicación GUI en java, en la cual uso serialización para los datos, pero cunado lo ejecuto, el .JAR los botones que usan la serialización , como por ejemplo el botón guardar no funciona. y la consola me tira este error:

```
Nota: Algunos archivos de entrada usan operaciones no verificadas o inseguras.
Nota: Recompile con -Xlint: desmarcado para más detalles.
```

Comment: El error que escribiste, no es necesariamente un error, se debe a un mensaje de advertencia, sin embargo siempre te deja compilar el archivo .JAR.  
Si quieres indagar más en el error debes compilar tu clase como indica el mensaje de error, a veces puede ser algun tipo de dato faltante, como indicó aquí Sam: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749904/8954823.    Para compilar `javac -Xlint:unchecked yourfilename.java`

Comment: Busca dentro de la carpeta Dist de tu proyecto y alli veras tu .Jar ejecutable. Esta carpeta esta en tu proyecto pero debes buscarlo como si buscaras un archivo normal.

Comment: define no funciona, porque la advertencia esa solo indica que tienes clases que soportan genéricos sin especificar genéricos